# Where are Adobe DTDs kept?

Tags: xml, adobe, svg, dtd

I can't believe how difficult these are to find. You'd THINK they'd be on adobe.com... anyway. Where can I download the following Adobe namespace DTDs?:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd" [
<!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_sfw "http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_adobe_xpath "http://ns.adobe.com/XPath/1.0/">
```

and...
http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLs (well, technically URIs) you've listed here are *probably* namespaces (I think that the 'ns_' prefix suggests that.

What you've listed above is the DTD for svg (via w3.org) with an internal subset declaring some entities. These aren't DTDs. Assuming that these are namespace declarations (DTDs don't do namespaces so using entities to kind-of declare them is a common hack), there is no reason for anything to exist to be downloaded.

A namespace is just a unique string. There doesn't need to be a resource there (that's why they are URIs not URLs).

I'd guess that you have an svg file with some adobe extensions in it. Is that right? An illustrator generated file possibly. If so, there may be a DTD (or schema) for these somewhere but nothing in the above indicates that there must be.

Sorry.

Comment: The file is "Save As SVG" from Illustrator. I assumed that since this is supposed to be an open standard there would be official documentation that covers adobes extensions. Thanks for explaining the namespace URIs.